# how to make a function out of img (which is href link ) and radio button (value or id) and goes to the next page

Tags: javascript, html, javaquery

I have this code:

```html
<div id="section">
  <h3 for="horoscope">choose horoscope</h3>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="period" value="week" id="week" checked/>
        <b>'weekly</b>

        <td>
          <input type="radio" name="period" value="month" id="month" />
          <b>monthly</b>

          <td>
            <input type="radio" name="period" value="year" id="year">
            <b>yearly</b>
          </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table id="horoscope" cellpadding="10">

    <td><a href="Aries.html"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/04/18/01/12/aries-36388_960_720.png" height="50px" width="53px" alt="aries" /></a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="Taurus.html"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/04/18/01/14/taurus-36397_960_720.png" height="50px" width="48px" alt="Taurus" /></a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="Gemini.html"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/04/18/01/13/gemini-36391_960_720.png" height="50px" width="49px" alt="Gemini" /></a>
    </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

so I want to do function that gets the period (monthly for example) and the sign (Taurus for exmaple) and on the next page it will go to the Taurus page and the place of monthly.

Another example: I choose Weekly and Aries-> in the next page-> weekly aries

How to do that?

Comment: you mean that if you select `weekly` then `Aries.html` will be redirect?

Comment: Aries.html#weekly

Comment: @kartikradadiya I am not the asker, user3779992 is.

Comment: @user3779992 i give you answer please checkout

Comment: @kartikradadiya if I changed the images to be checbox can I write the function window.location.href = link + "#" +$("input[name='sign']:checked").val()+ $("input[name='period']:checked").val();?

Comment: @user3779992 yes why not but can you tell us what you want exactly? i will try my best

Answer (score 0):

just do like this

> your HTML code

```
<div id="section">
        <h3 for="horoscope">choose horoscope</h3>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="period" value="week" id="week" checked/>
                    <b>'weekly</b>

                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="period" value="month" id="month"/>
                    <b>monthly</b>

                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="period" value="year" id="year">
                    <b>yearly</b>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table id="horoscope" cellpadding="10">
            <tr>
                <td><img onclick="redirect('Aries.html')"
                         src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/04/18/01/12/aries-36388_960_720.png" height="50px"
                         width="53px" alt="aries"/></td>
                <td><img onclick="redirect('Taurus.html')"
                         src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/04/18/01/14/taurus-36397_960_720.png" height="50px"
                         width="48px" alt="Taurus"/></td>
                <td><img onclick="redirect('Gemini.html')"
                         src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/04/18/01/13/gemini-36391_960_720.png" height="50px"
                         width="49px" alt="Gemini"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

> your script

```
<script>
function redirect(link) {
    window.location.href=link+"#"+$("input[name='period']:checked").val();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help for some reason it still doesn't work. I tried your code.